# Restore grayscale image from jpg file

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I have a 2-d numpy array, that I save as `.jpg` image.

For simplicity, let's assume my numpy array is the numbers between 0...255.

My problem is that once I save this array as `.jpg` image, I can't restore its values.

So my code is:

```
import cv2
from scipy.ndimage import imread
arr=np.array(range(256)).reshape(16,16)
cv2.imwrite('arr.jpg',arr)
restored=imread('arr.jpg')
print((arr==restored).sum()) #output is 224 rather than 256, i.e. 32 pixels are different!
```

So, how can I save the image so that I can see it, and restore the values afterwords?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: jpeg is lossy. your image is getting corrupted. use a lossless format like png instead.

Comment: @beaker thanks. Add this as an answer and I will happily accept it.